# Delphi. How to shift Frames using TreeView?

Tags: delphi, treeview, frame, shift

Please help me with my question.

I have TreeView and Frames, how can I shift them if I click on an item of TreeView?

Is it better to use PageControl (PageControl1.Pages[i].TabVisible := false;) instead of Frames or Frames fit better?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question *"how to ... using a TreeView?"* : Implement the OnChange event of the TreeView. The node parameter refers to the newly selected item.

About your second question *"Should I use Frames or a PageControl?"* : Well, one does not exclude the other and you perfectly can use both. Indeed, I advice to do so when you use the contents of such a TabPage multiple times. In those cases, place the Frame with `Align = alClient` on your TabPage.

Frames are usefull to design an arbitrary reusable container. For instance: you could set the same FrameType on every Page of the PageControl, assuming they all look the same but each working with different data.

Another possible minor advantage of using frames is not to get confused about all the controls on the TabPages.

But if every TabPage is unique in terms of visual style or control layout, then it's perfectly ok to not use frames and design the pages on the PageControl directly.

And about the shifting part: I don't exactly understand what you want to accomplish by setting the visibility of a tab, but shifting to another page (depending entirely on your implementation) based on the node could be as simple as:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := Node.Index;
end;
```